# How to compare wifi cards? in terms of build quaility

Tags: wireless-networking

I looking at 3 different usb wifi card for raspberry from Adafruit. 
http://www.adafruit.com/products/814
http://www.adafruit.com/products/1030

But I don't know which one to go with. I don't care the size or range. I'm more interested in reliability (how long it will die? or any kind of failure mode). I need some advices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't many differences between these mini wifi-cards. The adapters in this size are quite similar. They all have a 150Mbps down- and uplink. So, there aren't really significant differences. As you look at the internet, there aren't many "reviews" or comparisons of these little things, because they aren't really worth a review because of their similarity.

So my recommendation would be: Buy the cheapest one which provides **150Mbps(up- and downlink).**